# Why does C# DateTime parse "01/05/2020" the same regardless of culture?

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, culture

I am looking for someone to help me understand why this unit test passes.

Essentially we want to support various date formats but `en-CA` should be treated as `DD/MM/YYYY` and if client is using `en-us` culture then we want to treat the date as `MM/DD/YYYY`. I don't understand why this isn't the default behavior with `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.TryParse`.

```
[Fact]
public void DateTimeParse()
{
   var cultureUs = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("en-us");
   DateTime.TryParse("01/05/2020", cultureUs.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.None, out var d);
    
   var cultureCa = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("en-ca");
   DateTime.TryParse("01/05/2020", cultureCa.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.None, out var c);
    
   Assert.Equal(d.Month,c.Month);
}
```

Comment: Try `Assert.AreEqual(cultureUs.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, cultureCa.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);` Are those also the same?

Comment: There is a difference if you use `en-GB` though, so it seems like it is possible for Canadians to understand `01/05/2020` as Jan 5.

Comment: Use `GetCultureInfo` instead of `GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag` which is deprecated - does that change anything?

Comment: Not sure why this does parse at all - on my machine `cultureCa.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()` does not return any pattern supporting `/` (maybe related to [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/the-default-short-date-format-for-english-canada/ba-p/582763))

Comment: @GuruStron On my machine (macOS, .NET 5), it doesn't have anything with `/` either, but it does have patterns with `/` on [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0A4gDYD2ARgIbECWAXpcDaVANzoBulY2AxhMWAQwAU16VsAXmwBhAUNEBJKADNSREcDmDhI5WoBCAT0WaVAGUpQA5hErWRAFXsAKAEQioAWnFuAlOxoaqKUvAAW2C5cPAAO2DRQfPK64vgAIoxONAC2IgBipGDZjBrAAILExBnAWbkACow1YFAAzi5+fujY3bhIAJwuMQHoQA=).

Comment: @Igor strangely not. ShortDate for "en-ca" is "yyyy-mm-dd" and for "en-us' it is "m/d/yyyy"

Comment: Yeah, the usual format with `"en-CA"` would be `"2020-05-01"`. For that culture, the date separator is `"-"`.

Comment: @jepee Stig Nielsen. So this is just a bug with DateTime? As a Canadian I assure you DD/MM/YYYY format is very commonly used.

Comment: @user3695992 Are you running on Windows? If yes - see the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Side note: it is safe to explicitly show expected format to user and require exact match with `DateTime.ParseExact`. `Parse` tries to be smart trying several formats potentially picking opposite to what user expected. (Indeed if it is not user-entered value there is no excuse to use anything but ISO8601 format).

Comment: @GuruStron The list return by `GetAllDateTimePatterns()` for `"en-CA"` seems to differ between .NET Framework and .NET 5. Can you assume that `DateTime.Parse` and `.TryParse` will try each of these formats in order until one matches?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen not sure that they are as is at all (see the [remarks](here)). Also based on my quick debugging attemtpts I have not found any proof that it works that way)

Answer (score 2):

The formats of English (Canada) may be different from what you think. For example, the code:

```
    foreach (var code in new[] { "en-US", "en-CA", "en-GB", })
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Code {code}");
        var dtf = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(code).DateTimeFormat;
        Console.WriteLine(dtf.ShortDatePattern);
        Console.WriteLine(dtf.DateSeparator);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

writes:

```
Code en-US
M/d/yyyy
/

Code en-CA
yyyy-MM-dd
-

Code en-GB
dd/MM/yyyy
/
```

on my system.

When you use `TryParse` (and not `TryParseExact`) and none of the standard patterns of the date time format provider match, it is hard to know what happens(?).

Comment: Interesting. I have no idea why en-ca DateTimeFormat would by default parse the same as en-us. I tried en-ca, en-au, en-uk and ran into the same results. Thanks for providing en-gb.

Comment: `"en-GB"` was mentioned by Sweeper in a comment to your question. GB is the correct ISO code for the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, @user3695992.